# Scaling a single image with different scale factors

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I need to scale a single image with different scale factors. What is the solution for this? Suppose I created a function to generate a scale factor. Is it possible to scale an image row by row using these scale factors? Suppose my input image is like this [image]

Then suppose I need to scale the upper part of an image then the output should be like this (almost. Created manually using editor)
[image].

Because even after scaling the image should be continous, that is why I am planning to use different scale factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [perspective transform](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html#gsc.tab=0).

Its description is at the end of the page.

Comment: Thankyou for the help. But what the the thing is here we can do only perspective transform right? Suppose we have more than 4 points then what will we do? if we have to scale 2x in middle and scale .5x in the 1/4th of the image.. what will we do?